# What should our off-topic migration paths be?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

This is the list of possible migration paths that appear when you vote to close a question as off-topic.

This list should consist of the most appropriate sites, the ones which we will be migrating to most often. This is so that when we graduate, any use who has VTC privileges will be able to suggest a migration, instead of just mods.

The obvious ones are:

- Super User
- Unix and Linux

But what about;

- Server Fault
- Robotics?

What are your suggestions? What do you think is the main cause of off-topic questions?

Updated question with some not-terribly-useful stats:

- 7 questions >> Unix and Linux
- 1 question >> Super User
- 1 question >> Stack Overflow

There's probably not enough to form a pattern, but the good news is we're not migrating many questions away :)

Comment: Do you have a list of where we have migrated to? Have we migrated to SO?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: I do, would you like me to provide it, or will that load the question?

Comment: Personally, I think it's a good place to start.

Comment: Agrees with Alex, that examples will help

Comment: @AlexChamberlain & Andrew I'll give you a list this weekend.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain There you go.

Comment: Definitely add stackoverflow IMO.

Answer (score 5):

I would include Electronics.stackexchange.com. They are a great resource for questions about power supplies, interfacing circuits, etc.   There will probably be a decent overlap between the rpi audience here and the Arduino audience there.

Answer (score 1):

Having never yet found a need to "Propose to migrate" I'm not aware whether such a process has a pre-defined list of suggested migration venues.  If it does then fair enough, a list needs to be started.

However, such a list cannot be complete and exhaustive...

Surely the answer to this question is this:  If a question is considered off-topic here, is there a place where it will be on-topic?  If so, propose to migrate!  But the destination may be (potentially) any SE site.

As I can't edit the OP, here's a couple of additions to the list, {no doubt more to add in due course}

- Programmers SE
- Stack Overflow

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can have 4 sites, and also the appropriate meta site. What I was really asking is what sites are the most likely migrations, since only 4 can be shown.

Comment: OkeyDokey, thanks

Comment: Yeah, there is always an "Other".

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Pretty sure only mods or those who have mod tools can see that field.

Comment: Maybe a not sure then? There is definitely a way of letting someone else decide, yet still vote off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd list Unix & Linux; Super User; and Stack Overflow.

Monitor the situation for changes.